# Таблица в Visual Studio

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Как сделать подобную таблицу в Visual Studio? Я так понимаю, это DataGridView, или я ошибаюсь? Буду очень благодарен, если кто-то поможет кодом или укажет, где можно почитать или посмотреть.

[image]

Comment: какой язык? какой фреймворк?

Comment: Язык C#, про фреймворк не понял.

Comment: фреймворк - WPF, WinForms, ASP.NET, ASP.NET MVC или еще что-то?

Comment: @manticore: Рисование графики не является частью языка C#. Обычно используются фреймворки, которые рисуют «за вас», и заодно помогают вашей программе поддерживать событийно-ориентированную парадигму. Разные фреймворки имеют разные особенности. Популярными фреймворками являются, например, WPF, WinForms, ASP.NET, Silverlight.

Comment: А, теперь понял. WinForms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам сейчас начнут советовать различные фреймворки типа QT, WxWidgets и т.д. и будут правы, так как они продвинутые и очень облегчают программирование. Но "родным" решением в visual studio является WinForms. Вот, по-видимому, то, что вы хотели увидеть:

[image: то что вы хотели увидеть]

Это проект, созданный на Windows Forms и компонент DataGridView. Сразу добавлю, если вы перешли с Delphi, то WinForms это убогий ее аналог. Лучше изучайте QT, это самый популярный фреймворк, и он очень поможет вам в будущем.

Comment: +1, но я бы в качестве следующего шага после WinForms посоветовал WPF.